# How to update a subarray item in mongodb using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to update a subarray element using  c# and mongodb
I am trying to update LoginDate of tokennumber=444

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5cf67ad97739bfe8525e5353"),
"Email" : "eyal@gmail.com",
"Username" : "eyal",
"Password" : "1234",
"Tokens" : [ 
    {
        "Tokennumber" : "123",
        "Valid" : "true",
        "LoginDate" : ISODate("2019-06-04T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "Tokennumber" : "444",
        "Valid" : true,
        "LoginDate" : ISODate("2019-06-08T06:41:05.313Z")
    }
  ]
 }
```

I have applied this code

```
var result = _users.FindOneAndUpdate(
            Builders<Users>.Filter.ElemMatch(to => to.tokens, t => 
 t.tokennumber == decryptedtoken),
            Builders<Users>.Update
            .Set("LoginDate", DateTime.Now)
         );
```

it  added a Logindate node and didnt update a current one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use -1 to indicate the use of the positional operator (documented [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531?focusedCommentId=846770&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-846770))

```
var result =
    _users.FindOneAndUpdate(
        Builders<Users>.Filter.ElemMatch(to => to.tokens, t => t.tokennumber == decryptedtoken),
        Builders<Users>.Update.Set(to => to.tokens[-1].logindate, DateTime.Now)
    );
```

Comment: Hey thnks for your reply ,but i get building error when  i use to.tokens[-1] ,it says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IEnumerable<Token>

Comment: Is the type of your "Tokens" property IEnumerable<Token>? In this case, define it as Token[].

Comment: O.k i use your suggestion and put [-1] but and it works but i have a remark under the -1 that index should start at zero

Comment: Either ignore the warning, or use a private var posOp = -1;